# Group by based on a value of a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

i have the following DataFrame:

[image]

it contains user_ids, tweets, and the classification of the tweet as negative and positive.

i want to create a new dataframe that has the following columns:

1. user_id
2. count of negative tweets by that user_id
3. count of positive tweets by that user_id

Thanks

Comment: you had a different question here that i answered..now you have another question completely. not only have you not accepted my work on your first question. Now others cant upvote my answer to your first question. On top of this i cant get rep for this new question.

Comment: @BlackFox my friend, it was the same question. the original question said that the new dataframe should contain column that count negative tweets, and column that contains negative tweets. your answer does not do that. you even said that yourself and deleted the comment?? i accepted the question, have a good day!

Comment: This is a new question and should be created alongside the first question you edited. Its like im answer question 1 and 2 on a quiz or test or something.......comments and answers or for everyone on SO not just the person asking the question. thus deleting that message wen you unmarked my answer as the answer and did not change the question back as discussed.

Comment: trying to hlep but im wasting a morning on this question lol. im out!

Comment: @BlackFox i only unaccepted the answer because you said that i was right and you can post a new answer. i unaccepted that answer so i would accept the other answer that you post :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df.groupby(['user_id','classification'])['user_id'].count()
```

Comment: i added a required sample output. it looks a bit different from what that code does

Comment: Looks like you are new tostack overflow welcome. Please change the question back to the original one and up vote this answer. Next make a new question around the current post. I would be happy to work on this new question and post a new answer for additional efforts

Comment: Hi, i can go back to the old one. but, the question is still the same. i only added the location to the dataframe because i forgot to include it. otherwise, the first three points are not changed. it said that the new dataframe should contain the first 3 points as columns. i will up vote this answer anyway. thanks!

Comment: df.groupby(["user_id", "classification"])["user_id"].count().reset_index(name="count")    
df['positive_tweets'] = df.groupby(['classification','count'])['classification'].count().reset_index(name="positive_tweets")